# How to get past Grub prompt during boot?

Tags: installation, grub2, wubi

I am new to Ubuntu and am stuck. Please help as I do not know much about Linux or command line. I am a Windows 7 user.

Here are the steps I took to install Ubuntu:

- I downloaded "*ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso*" file
- Further via 7zip, extracted the Ubuntu iso file in Windows only.
- Ran wubi.exe from the extract and installed Ubuntu in E drive. C drive contains Windows 7 and iso file was saved here only. Wubi.exe downloaded some files for around an hour.
- The installation was successful and it asked for a reboot. I got a screen with some characters and after an hour or so I forced the shutdown.
- On reboot I got the option to select Windows or Ubuntu. On selecting Ubuntu I get this and cannot proceed further.

> GNU GRUB version 2.00-7ubuntu11
>
> Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.

[image: screenshot]

How do I get past this grub prompt?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't force shutdown Ubuntu. It's often not required as you can safely reboot using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd>. (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrntScr</kbd> if you have no <kbd>SysRq</kbd> key, they're the same).

It's common to cause corruption when hard rebooting, especially on Wubi installs where there is a virtual disk that's stored on the `NTFS` file system, but it contains an `ext4` file system.

So, since you just installed - I'd recommend reinstalling. Or doing a normal dual boot. To clean up the file system corruption you should first run `chkdsk /f` from Windows.

Also, if you had problems installing you might have some incompatible hardware or something that requires a closed-source driver (not included automatically). i.e. if you have a Radeon or Nvidia graphics card you should boot with `nomodeset`. You can find out how through this link: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

have you gone through https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2?rd=Grub2#Encountering_the_dreaded_Grub2_boot_prompt

It says you are getting the dreaded GRUB Prompt ... GRUB was not properly configured, use the commands in the link to boot your system.